# Can stunnel be used to round robin tcp connections without SSL?

Tags: load-balancing, stunnel, round-robin

Today, I'm already using stunnel to provide SSL termination to a set of TCP services where the connections are round-robin'ed, this is done, for example, like follows:

```
[myserv]
accept = 443
connect = 9274
connect = 9275
connect = 9276
connect = 9277
```

I'd like to do the same thing but where the accept port doesn't provide SSL termination, it would just round-robin the accepted connections to the backend services.

I'd like to know if there's a way to do that with stunnel, or if there's a similar linux service that can do that.

Comment: I think stunnel's sole purpose is SSL termination.  Try nginx if you want a simple round-robin load balance.